# Quicksort Stability Demo

Tags: java, quicksort

I understand that quicksort is indeed unstable (incase of primitives)because of the way partitioning works/long-distance exchanges. I am trying to understand what happens if quicksort is used to sort complex objects with equal keys. Essentially why java `Collections.sort` doesn't use Quicksort.

Here is a demo app that I created to aid my understanding. As per this app, objects with equal keys seem to retain their input order. I know that I have some understanding gaps here. I did search on the web but most examples are based on integer sorting.

Please help me understand quicksort stability issues.

> **DEMO**

```
import java.util.*;

public class QuickSortStabilityDemo {

    static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
        String name;
        int rank;

        public Node(String name, int rank) {
            this.name =  name;
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node o) {
            int result = this.name.compareTo(o.name);
            if(result == 0) {
                return this.rank == o.rank ? 0 : this.rank < o.rank ? -1: 1;
            }
            else {
                return result;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + this.name + "," + this.rank + "," + this.hashCode() + "}" ;
        }
    }

    //Fisher-Yates 
        public void shuffleArray(Node[] arr) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int n = arr.length;

            for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
                int j = random.nextInt(i+1);
                Node temp = arr[i];
                arr[i]= arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }

        }

        private void swap(Node[] arr, int i, int j) {
            Node temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }

        public void sort(Node[] arr, int start, int end) {  

            if(start >= end) {
                return;
            }



            Node pivot = arr[start];

            int lt = start;
            int gt = end;


            for(int current=start+1;current <= gt; ) {

                if(arr[current].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                    swap(arr,current,lt);  
                    current++; 
                    lt++; 
                }
                else if(arr[current].compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
                    swap(arr,current,gt); 
                    gt--; 
                }
                else {
                    current++;
                }

            }
            sort(arr,start,lt-1);
            sort(arr,gt+1,end);


        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            QuickSortStabilityDemo sort = new QuickSortStabilityDemo();
            String[] cities = {"New York","Jersey City","Pittsburgh"};

            List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i=0;i <3;i++) {
                for(int j=1; j <=3; j++) {
                    list.add(new Node(cities[i],i));
                }
            }

            Node[] arr = list.toArray(new Node[list.size()]);

            System.out.println("Before sorting...");

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

            sort.sort(arr,0,arr.length-1);

            System.out.println("After sorting...");


            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

In the original demo I posted, the data was a bit contrived.  The properties of objects within each set are same and is done purposefully. I did not shuffle the array; set the pivot to the start element of portion of array that is being sorted.

As I debugged my demo further, event though **NY** and **JC** objects retained their original order **Pgh** objects did change their original insertion order. Therefore I did see the instability of the algorithm.

I used hashcode of these elements to track their original insertion order.

Here is the output from a run:

```
[{New York,0,1163157884}
, {New York,0,1956725890}
, {New York,0,356573597}
, {Jersey City,1,1735600054}
, {Jersey City,1,21685669}
, {Jersey City,1,2133927002}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1836019240}
, {Pittsburgh,2,325040804}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1173230247}
]
After sorting
[{Jersey City,1,1735600054}
, {Jersey City,1,21685669}
, {Jersey City,1,2133927002}
, {New York,0,1163157884}
, {New York,0,1956725890}
, {New York,0,356573597}
, {Pittsburgh,2,325040804}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1173230247}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1836019240}
]
```

If I shuffle the input array, the instability of the algorithm is more apparent.

Here is the output from a run (**with shuffled input**):

```
Original order
[{New York,0,1163157884}
, {New York,0,1956725890}
, {New York,0,356573597}
, {Jersey City,1,1735600054}
, {Jersey City,1,21685669}
, {Jersey City,1,2133927002}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1836019240}
, {Pittsburgh,2,325040804}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1173230247}
]
After shuffling
[{New York,0,1163157884}
, {New York,0,1956725890}
, {Pittsburgh,2,325040804}
, {Jersey City,1,2133927002}
, {New York,0,356573597}
, {Jersey City,1,1735600054}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1836019240}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1173230247}
, {Jersey City,1,21685669}
]
After sorting
[{Jersey City,1,21685669}
, {Jersey City,1,2133927002}
, {Jersey City,1,1735600054}
, {New York,0,1956725890}
, {New York,0,356573597}
, {New York,0,1163157884}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1173230247}
, {Pittsburgh,2,1836019240}
, {Pittsburgh,2,325040804}
]
```

Please let me know if any suggestions on this answer.

Comment: I see that someone down voted my answer. Can you please let me know why?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the unstable result, you should NOT compare `rank`.

If you compare both name and rank, then there is a strict order between the items, then the result is stable.

The unstable result only occurs when two items equal to each other.

Here is my version:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class QuickSortStabilityDemo {

    static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
        String name;
        int rank;

        public Node(String name, int rank) {
            this.name = name;
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node o) {
            return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + this.name + "," + this.rank + "}";
        }
    }

    private void swap(Node[] arr, int i, int j) {
        Node temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }

    public void sort(Node[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start >= end) {
            return;
        }
        Node pivot = arr[start];

        int lt = start;
        int gt = end;
        for (int current = start + 1; current <= gt; ) {
            if (arr[current].compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                swap(arr, current, lt);
                current++;
                lt++;
            } else if (arr[current].compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
                swap(arr, current, gt);
                gt--;
            } else {
                current++;
            }

        }
        sort(arr, start, lt - 1);
        sort(arr, gt + 1, end);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuickSortStabilityDemo sort = new QuickSortStabilityDemo();

        String[] cities = {"New York", "Jersey City", "Pittsburgh"};

        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                list.add(new Node(cities[j], i));
            }
        }

        Node[] arr = list.toArray(new Node[list.size()]);
        System.out.println("Before sorting...");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        sort.sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        System.out.println("After sorting...");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Before sorting...
[{New York,1}, {Jersey City,1}, {Pittsburgh,1}, {New York,2}, {Jersey City,2}, {Pittsburgh,2}, {New York,3}, {Jersey City,3}, {Pittsburgh,3}]
After sorting...
[{Jersey City,1}, {Jersey City,3}, {Jersey City,2}, {New York,2}, {New York,1}, {New York,3}, {Pittsburgh,2}, {Pittsburgh,3}, {Pittsburgh,1}]
```

You can see that `{Jersey City,2}` is BEFORE `{Jersey City,3}` before sorting.

But after sorting, `{Jersey City,2}` is AFTER `{Jersey City,3}`.

This is the unstable result.

PS: If you use other stable algorithms, the result must be `{J,1},{J,2},{J,3},{N,1},{N,2},{N,3},{P,1},{P,2},{P,3}`.

Comment: Right, only compare names.  If you compare all the fields in a class then the result will always appear to be fully ordered.

Comment: @shawn - Thanks for answering my question. If similar objects contain at least one distinct property and the comparator function is handled on non distinct properties, then quicksort will produce unstable result. This is why in my original demo, I made sure all NY objects rank 1 and JC objects rank 2 and Pgh rank 3. And I used hashcode to track the objects original order.

Comment: You must have misunderstood something ? Assume you have objects with 2 fields (A,B), or objects with 3 fields (X,Y,Z).   Is there any difference between: (A equals, B unique) and (X equals, Y equals, Z unique) ??  Why do not you combine X+Y to B to make them the same?  Think about (A=myName, B=myRank), or (X=yourName, Y=yourRank, Z=hashCode)